# Using object methods on Node server and web client over JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a Javascript library that I want to use on a web browser and also on a Node.js backend. In the library, I have multiple objects with methods defined like so:

```
function foo() {
  this.bar = 200;
  this.someMethod = function(baz) {
    return this.bar + baz;
  };
}

var x = new foo();
```

And I can use it in the client or the Node.js server by doing the following:

```
x.someMethod(5);
   => (returns 205)
```

Now, when I `JSON.stringify` my object, it shows up without the method.

```
var string = JSON.stringify(x);
   => {"bar":200}
```

Which means I can't unpack the JSON on my server and use the same methods.

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(string);
document.write(parsed.someMethod(5));
   => (doesn't do anything. the methods are gone!)
```

In a class based system I'd just use a copy constructor. Something that would reconstruct the object from JSON.

```
function foo_copy_constructor(parsed_json) {
  f = new foo();
  f.bar = parsed_json.bar;
  return f;
}

var z = foo_copy_constructor(parsed);
z.someMethod(5);
   => (returns 205 like it should)
```

( jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7FdDe/ )

**Basically, Is there a better way than this?**

Many of my objects contain instances of other objects I've written with their own methods, and this seems like it would get tedious to build a constructor for every object since both the client and the server use the same library and object definitions. I know that JavaScript is based on prototypes, but I don't really understand them since I've just started with JavaScript and am used to Python and class-based languages.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: This is not related to prototypical inheritance. If you want to transfer data along the wire, you need to serialize them. Serializing functions is not exactly trivial.

Comment: I don't think I want to serialize them, just use them both places. I have definitions for the functions on both client and server, I want to be able to say `foo.someMethod()` on the client, pass the object over to the server, and add the methods back from the server's copy of their definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` only stringifies the objects that have the `toJSON` method. So you could simply add the `toJSON` method to your methods. (Remember, functions are objects too.)

```
function A() {
    this.method = function() { console.log(1); };
}

var c = new A();
JSON.stringify(c);
"{}"

A.prototype.otherMethod = function() { console.log(1); };

var c = new A();
JSON.stringify(c);
"{}"

Function.prototype.toJSON = function() { return this.toString(); };
JSON.stringify(c);
"{"method":"function () { console.log(1); }"}"
```

However, when parsing this back, you get the function as a string. So you have to the strings back to functions with something like this:

```
var d = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(c));
Object.keys(d).forEach(function(k) {

    // If it starts with "function"
    if (/^function/.test(d[k])) {

        // Get the body of the function
        var f = d[k].match(/{(.*)}/).pop();

        // Replace the string with a real function
        d[k] = new Function(f);
    }
});

d.method();
1
```

---

However, instead of messing with javascript like this, I'd rather suggest that you use a well-tested library like [now.js](https://github.com/Flotype/now).

Comment: Now.js looks like it could help me out a lot! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ZachHall It appears that the now.js project has been abandoned by its developers (despite being very promising) - I wonder if there's a suitable replacement for it. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/nowjs/FZXWZr22vn8